# How to create executable from multiple exe's?

Tags: windows-installer, executable, packing

My program wants some exe's to be run to setup the environment of my application.
so i want to create a executable which will contains multiple exe's inside.

can anyone suggest me how can I do the same?

thanks

sam

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a simple SFX archive out of your EXE files? Depending on your real needs, this might be enough...